# camel case to snake case error with underscore and removing extra letter?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to convert words from camel case to snake case, and to remove the word 'set' at the start. I am almost there, but the error is that it removes the very last letter, and also adds an underscore at the start:

eg. setStudentNumber becomes _Student_Numbe instead of Student_Number.

What am I doing wrong? Please help :)

```
import re

def CamelCase(word):
    result= re.search(r'^set.',word)


#CamelCase("setStudentNumber")

def convert(name):
    CamelCase(name)
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).strip('set')


print(convert("setStudentNumber"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import re

def convert(name):
    name = re.sub('^set', "", name)                   #Remove set
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name)  #snake_case

print(convert("setStudentNumber"))
```

Comment: @UnbearableLightness sorry I did not understand...OP requires `Student_Number`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness..I believe OP needs `Student_Number` --> "setStudentNumber becomes _Student_Numbe instead of Student_Number"

Answer (score 0):

try this ;)

```py
import re

name = "setStudentNumber"
name = name.replace("set","",1) if name.startswith("set") else name
print (re.sub(r'([A-Z])', r'_\1',  name))
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to keep most parts of you code:

```
import re

def convert(name):
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name.strip('set'))


print(convert("setStudentNumber"))
```